# We need basic tag inheritance functionality

Tags: feature-request, tags

OK, that's not a question. I went round in a few loops trying to find anything on tags, specifically to do with synonyms and alias. I think tag inheritance is a more appropriate label and yes, I found some questions requesting inheritance after writing this, so I changed direction. However, most of my initial question was put to the bottom of this post for reference.

Duplicate? **No**. There is a very simple use case that needs to be implemented. Forget the edge cases and anything possibly relatable through inheritance that causes more than a moment to question its feasibility.

I've brought this up months ago, but maybe in the wrong light, so let’s be blunt and address the elephant in the room.

Tag searches should not use a tag as a token that only matches results with that exact tag. Like if we matched tags as tokens then: `[php]` != `[php-8]`, but if you searched for the tag `[php]` then you would expect results to include `[php-8]`, would you not?

Why isn't there a link between related tags, such as `[php]` `[php-8]` and `[php-8.2]`, to assist in retrieving relevant results when used in searches?

Currently if an entry isn't tagged with all three then it won't show up if you search for the missing tag. Searching within the `[php]` tag should include results tagged with `[php-8]`, even if they are not also tagged with `[php]`.

In what context, would anyone want results relevant to `[php]` and not `[php-8]`? Maybe a search for `[php-8]` should exclude entries tagged `[php]` without the `[php-8]` or `[php-8.2]` tag as well.

Like the laws of (co/contra)variance in object-oriented programming, the more specific (child) tag is relevant when a search is tagged with its less specific (parent) tag, but a parent tag is not implied when its extending child tag is searched.

If all questions relating to `[php-8]` were tagged with both `[php-8]` and `[php]` then there would not be any problem.

The inheritance need not be visible, but it must exist to facilitate proper searching.

Let me find an example. I'll search for `[php]` and `[php-8]` separately, both ordered by newest to find missing entries within the returned results.

Here you can see the [Encrypt in JS and Decrypt in PHP using AES encryption algorithm in GCM and Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78012432/encrypt-in-js-and-decrypt-in-php-using-aes-encryption-algorithm-in-gcm-and-base6) question tagged `[php-8]` is not found in a search for the `[php]` tag, because it is not explicitly set on the question.

[image: Example tag searches]

Does it make sense?

As far as I know, it has not been implemented:

#### TL:DR:

---

*this is going to generate great feedback; I can feel it. Oh well, you only live once. I, on the other hand, have 5 fingers (no thumb).*

[suggest-tag-synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) removes redundant tags, linking content to the canonical tag synonym

> Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with the correct tags.

[tag-excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) doesn't mention relationships between co-existing tags. Neither does [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) or [tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) or [create-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

[We need some kind of tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) wants to allow tag misspelling which is not what I'm talking about.

[interesting-topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) offers an explanation of searching with tags that don't solve the issue.

---

So did you get the PHP / elephant reference I made?

Comment: i mean, yea, 100%, why shouldn't this exist? however... will it ever?

Comment: the solutions simple, stop using tags as tokens and actually search the contents of the tag names.. this would include things like [php-8] in a search for [php] without much implementation

Comment: eh, well, that has it's own problems. Tag hierarchies would allow more people rising through the ranks to gain curation abilities through earning gold badges that are actually relevant to what they're doing, where as just fixing this with search means you'll have some tags that happen to match the prefix but be entirely irrelevant to what is being searched for. I'd love to have loose tag hierarchies

Comment: haha yeah everything does, it's just my turn to get annoyed at it i guess

Comment: There was, at one point, an investigation into how questions/answers could be annotated with which versions they refer to.  I'm not sure anything actually came of it (and it may be a somewhat intractable problem in the general case).  Tag inheritance might be a decent middle ground.

Comment: This is an A-tier (if not S-tier) request that has been toyed with a bit by CMs in the past (and _long_ requested by users). It'd be great to have some sort of 'parent tag' (especially if it auto applied parent tags when a child tag was selected, and didn't count/was separate from the 5 tag limit on questions) but as Kevin B mentioned... the issue is not the desire or even the plan, but the will of the company to actually implement such a useful feature when instead they can work on AI stuff or firing people or whatever.

Comment: Does [php*] solve your problem?

Comment: [Codidact has had this since mid-2020](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/39539), BTW.

Comment: I would actually prefer my search for `[php]` not be cluttered with stuff from `[php-8]` and friends (especially as I can achieve the latter by searching with wildcards already (`[php*]`), getting the inverse is significantly harder (`-[php-8] -[php-7] …`)).

Comment: Meh. The example isn't all that thrilling since I'm more and more convinced that `language-major` tags aren't all that useful (and totally convinced for `language-major-minor`). Too many posters needlessly add them without knowing whether the problem actually is version dependent, and most of the time a collection of version-independent answers is better.

Comment: @KevinB I had no idea we could do that! yeah it kind of does solve the problem.. I think searching was really the only issue for me, one other that I'm not fussed over would be that the collective isn't linked, for example with the `[phpunit]` tag.

Comment: @cafce25 just making conversation, i'm wondering what you would search for under the `[php]` tag that you wouldn't want to get questions relating to specific versions? I get that the versioned tags should be for issues in those versions but I think (blindly) they would be used more to identify the version used when faced with the question. Fair enough if code needed to adapt with new versions.. I'm rambling on, I've understood a bit here in the comments, alot more in alot less time than I've spent searching SO for sure, thanks all

Comment: Well `[php]` was just an example, I just prefer to get the thing I search for and not a bunch of related things. I'm also not generally interested in legacy version specific Q/As (`[php-7]`, `[php-5]`, …) unless I specifically ask for one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi hah, thrilling, i didn't even think it would get any attention. I don't really get the `language-major` tags because they seem to be everywhere (except for right now when I searched to test my thoughts hah), OK i'll now say everywhere they shouldn't be.

Comment: Maybe that's just how I use the sites search though, as a narrowly scoped, precision tool, when I need a more general search, I use external tools anyways.

Comment: @cafce25 yeah for sure, I don't care at all if the issue is in PHP 8.2. I won't use it again without some irrelevant or far out edge case. Also don't like getting half way through some content about enumerations to find out, it's related to a poly fill or work around for versions before enums were added as a language feature.

Comment: @cafce25 my searching skills are deteriorating by the minute. was so easy before engines adopted things like dates, popularity or relevance. what happened to good old "find this exact sequence of characters" that discovered so many gems for me in the 90s. turning into a snowball effect rant about `views++` => `ranking++` => `views++` => `++ ++ ++`  `·∙⋅•∘⦁●`